# Is it possible to set a specific formatter for an ILoggerProvider wrapped by serilog?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have followed the instructions from https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore and have the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    static readonly LoggerProviderCollection Providers = new LoggerProviderCollection();

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(new CompactJsonFormatter())
            .WriteTo.Providers(Providers)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            })
            .UseSerilog(providers: Providers)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

`logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()` configures logging to azure blob storage with `BlobLoggerProvider`, serilog is able to use this provider and write to the blob storage.

I would like to change the formatter for the `BlobLoggerProvider` to `CompactJsonFormatter`, but I can't figure out how. Is it possible to set a specific formatter for an `ILoggerProvider` wrapped by serilog?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this is not possible to set a specific formatter for an `ILoggerProvider` wrapped by serilog, nor would it make much sense.

Serilog has a sink that forwards log calls to each `ILoggerProvider` instance in the `Providers` collection. It is not possible to configure output formatting in this sink.

```
class LoggerProviderCollectionSink : ILogEventSink, IDisposable
    {
        // ...

        public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            string categoryName = null;

            if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out var sourceContextProperty) &&
                sourceContextProperty is ScalarValue sourceContextValue &&
                sourceContextValue.Value is string sourceContext)
            {
                categoryName = sourceContext;
            }

            var level = LevelConvert.ToExtensionsLevel(logEvent.Level);
            var slv = new SerilogLogValues(logEvent.MessageTemplate, logEvent.Properties);

            foreach (var provider in _providers.Providers)
            {
                var logger = provider.CreateLogger(categoryName);

                logger.Log(
                    level,
                    default, 
                    slv,
                    logEvent.Exception,
                    (s, e) => s.ToString());
            }
        }
        // ...      
    }
```

[LoggerProviderCollectionSink.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/Extensions/Logging/LoggerProviderCollectionSink.cs)

The `ILoggerProvider` implementation `BlobLoggerProvider` inherits from `BatchingLoggerProvider`, the logger created by the `BlobLoggerProvider` is a `BatchingLogger`. This logger does its own formatting of the log message before writing it to a queue, so it would not be much help if serilog provided a json string to the logger.

```
internal class BatchingLogger : ILogger
    {
        // ... 

        public void Log<TState>(DateTimeOffset timestamp, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
            {
                return;
            }

            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz"));
            builder.Append(" [");
            builder.Append(logLevel.ToString());
            builder.Append("] ");
            builder.Append(_category);

            var scopeProvider = _provider.ScopeProvider;
            if (scopeProvider != null)
            {
                scopeProvider.ForEachScope((scope, stringBuilder) =>
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(" => ").Append(scope);
                }, builder);

                builder.AppendLine(":");
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append(": ");
            }

            builder.AppendLine(formatter(state, exception));

            if (exception != null)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(exception.ToString());
            }

            _provider.AddMessage(timestamp, builder.ToString());
        }
        // ...
    }
```

[BatchingLogger](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/v3.1.4/src/Logging/Logging.AzureAppServices/src/BatchingLogger.cs)